# How to display a location of a place in android app

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am looking for a way to display a location of a place inside an android application. I have the longitude and Latitude coordinates of the place stored inside a MySQL database, now I want to retrieve them (Longitude and latitude)and display the exact location in the application. thanks

Comment: Are u using GoogleMaps in android, if yes show us code, may be we can help..!

Comment: Can you be more specific on How u need to display the exact location like Is it in a google map as a marker or not

Comment: do you want it in a map view? or just the details?

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you want it on a map view with a marker.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

This should be added to you xml file of the activity you want the Map to be in.
Then in your activity,

```
GoogleMap googleMap;
MapFragment mapFragment;
```

Initialize this in you onCreate;

```
mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

and then create the override method, `onMapReady()`

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap) {
    googleMap = gMap;
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    try {
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } catch (SecurityException se) {

    }

    //Edit the following as per you needs
    googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    //

    LatLng placeLocation = new LatLng(***YOUR LAT***, ***YOUR LNG***); //Make them global
    Marker placeMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(placeLocation)
                  .title(***NAME OF PLACE HERE***));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(placeLocation));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 1000, null);
}
```

I think that should give you what you want. Comment if you need anything else.

Comment: well formatted step-to-step instruction. this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: is there a @override method onMapReady()??

Comment: Very Good Explanation hope i could accept that answer

Comment: @ArnoldBrown `YourClassName implements OnMapReadyCallback`

Answer (score 1):

To get the location details using latitude and longitude please use the below code

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            //Add mapView  activity.xml
            <com.google.android.maps.MapView
                        android:id="@+id/map_view"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:apiKey="your api key"

                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:layout_below="@id/tv_location" />

        //Add Activity
         // Getting reference to MapView
                mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
                googleMap = mapView.getMap();

    final LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pin));
            final CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(14f).tilt(70).build();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
 googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this);
    String locationName = list.get(i);
    Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);
    List<Address> addressList = null;
    try {
        addressList = coder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Address location = addressList.get(0);
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng helpcenter = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(helpcenter)
            .title(list.get(i)));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(helpcenter, 6f));
```

Comment: In this code you can find any place using place name.Here list is a listview and list.get(i) is the specific place name