# How to show name and location on the fragment map in MapsActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to retrieve the location of trademark places in specific cities. I want to display the place name and LatLng. How do I do that?

````
    private String name;
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;


    public Location(String name, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.name = name;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " (" + latitude + ", " + longitude + ")";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }```
````

Comment: You can have latitude and longitude by using Google map, what about name of location?

Comment: Have a look on below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630786/how-to-display-a-location-of-a-place-in-android-app